# How to dissolve cobalt ferrite spinel for cleaning reactor?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, cleaning

I put some cobalt ferrite powder and did some catalytic test and I can't clean my reactor very well. I have already used aqua regia, hydrochloric and nitric acids, sodium hydroxide at high concentration and also piranha solution, but nothing worked.

Comment: What exactly was "*some catalytic test*", and what your reactor is made of? Please [edit] the details into your question to help others help you.

Comment: Be aware that not well described question context often leads to "a crystal ball scenario".

Comment: What is the residue? If it's an oxide, try a **reducing** agent, e.g., sodium metabisulfite. And as mentioned by others, of what is the reactor made? Have you already damaged it with your experimentation?

Answer (score 3):

I would do what steel strip manufacturers do: use hydrochloric acid solution, which pickles off the mixed iron oxides in hot mill scale (including $\ce{Fe3O4}$, which would likely act similarly to your cobalt ferrite). But you may want to allow some time, because [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetite) reports that $\ce{Fe3O4}$ dissolves "slowly" in hydrochloric acid. (The industrial pickling process is aided by keeping the acid hot, typically 85-90°C; the presence of the steel strip itself and the micron size of the film.)